# Add New Entries to Key Value Pair Array in Type Script

Tags: typescript, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I am trying to add a new key value pair entry to the existing dictionary. Here's the TypeScript to define the dictionary:

```
export class DictionaryClass {
    Dictionary?: { [key: string]: boolean };
}

export function getDictionary(locale: string) {

let dictionaryClass = new DictionaryClass();
dictionaryClass.Dictionary = {
 "ShowButton": true
};
dictionaryClass.Dictionary.forEach(v => { "ShowImage": false; });

return dictionaryClass;
```

}

I googled around and I was told `ForEach` would be the method to add new entries, but it doesn't seem to have such method.

Any other idea to approach this?

Comment: In addition to my answer below: `let dictionaryClass = new Dictionary();` should be `let dictionaryClass = new DictionaryClass();`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen corrected, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the key in advance:

```
dictionaryClass.Dictionary.ShowImage = false;
```

If you don't know the key in advance, you can reference the key using square brackets:

```
let k:string = 'ShowImage'; // Or any value
dictionaryClass.Dictionary[k] = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

That should just be:

```
dictionaryClass.Dictionary.ShowImage = false;
```

The `forEach()` function is used to iterate over arrays. You're dealing with an [*object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) instead of an array, and have no need to iterate.